# Survey on how frequently a group use a particular device: Which analysis methods?

Tags: survey, wilcoxon-signed-rank, friedman-test

I surveyed a group of photographers and asked them how frequently they used a particular type of lens for a specific type of photograph. I now want to find out which lens or lenses are the most commonly used for each type of photograph. There were four lens types and five types of photographs and I had 50 participants.

The participants responded using a 0-10 scale with 0 being never and 10 being all the time.

My hypothesis is there is a significant difference between the choice of lens for a particular style of photograph

As i am new to statistics i want to check I am correct in thinking the following:

1. As the data is ordinal i do not need to normalize the results.
2. I should create box plots
   3.I should use a Friedman test followed by a Wilcoxon signed rank test